# How to mock/repoint urls to external services of already released managed package to different testing envs (e.g. qa/staging/uat heroku apps)

Tags: managed-package, namedcredentials, httpcalloutmock, canvas-app, environment

Our managed package uses a lot of external services in a form of nodejs heroku applications.

Integrations are implemented in different ways:

- apex callout + named credentials
- canvas connected app

After creating released version of our managed package, we are conducting different types of testing in staging/integration/performance/uat orgs.

The trouble here is that urls in released version of our managed package are pointing to production version of external services, while we would like to be able to "repoint" them to staging/integration/performance/uat apps instead to test appropriate changes.

Creating separate package versions for each specific set of services endpoints is not an option for us, since there are a lot of services and package version creation takes tremendous amount of time.

What would be the preferred way to rule out this situation and conduct testing of released managed package in combination with desired version/type of heroku services (each org may require different set of services urls but still the same package version)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: IMHO, you should be using configuration (e.g. named credentials, custom metadata types, external sites, etc.) to provide the end point definitions required in the managed package, thus allowing these to be set or reset in specific installations.

Comment: @PhilW The thing is that SF doesn't allow to update url inside named credentials when managed package is installed, since it's part of managed package itself. Same is about url in canvas connected app. Everything is set as it was defined in package version upload time.

Comment: Consider not packaging the named credential and instead require that they be created on install. Thus they are outside the package and are subscriber editable. If that's no good from the security perspective, package multiple variants of the named credentials and use a CMT to select which ones to use in a given org. Or use something other than named credentials...